# using multiple fork and join class to split task,Is a good practice or not?

Tags: java, fork-join, forkjoinpool

For my work I have to develop a small Java application that parses very large text files(~6800 kb), so I 'm trying to optimize it a little to make futher process. Splitting line with equalto (=) as first fork task and for splitting with comma and some calulations using 2nd fork task. Will this lead to good performace with multiple fork task for single application.

1) First fork and join process:

```
 @Override
protected Map < String, String > compute() {
SplitString lineSplit = new SplitString();
Map < String, String > splitUrl = new HashMap < > ();
// list size is less than limit process actual task.

if (readAllLines.size() < Constant.LIMIT) {
    // splitUrl map stores the splitter lines with equal_to
    splitUrl = lineSplit.splittingLines(readAllLines);

} else { // list size greater than limit splits task in to two and process it.
    // split task into sub task and stores it in list
    List < String > left = readAllLines.subList(Constant.ZERO, readAllLines.size() / 2);
    List < String > right = readAllLines.subList(readAllLines.size() / 2, readAllLines.size());
    SplitTask firstTask = new SplitTask(left);
    SplitTask secondTask = new SplitTask(right);
    // forks the firstTask
    firstTask.fork();
    // forks the secondTask
    secondTask.fork();
    // join the task in splitUrl map
    splitUrl.putAll(firstTask.join());
    splitUrl.putAll(secondTask.join());
}
return splitUrl;
}
```

2) second fork and join process:

```
 @Override
protected Map < String, Map < String, Integer >> compute() {
    SplitString ruleSplit = new SplitString();
    Map < String, Map < String, Integer >> response = new HashMap < > ();
    // list size is less than limit process actual task.

    if (KeyList.size() < Constant.LIMIT) {
        // splitUrl map stores the splitter lines with equal_to
        response = ruleSplit.calculatingRuleTime(result, KeyList);

    } else { // list size greater than limit splits task in to two and process it.
        // split task into sub task and stores it in list.
        List < String > left = KeyList.subList(Constant.ZERO, KeyList.size() / 2);
        List < String > right = KeyList.subList(KeyList.size() / 2, KeyList.size());
        SplitRuleTask firstTask = new SplitRuleTask(result, left);
        SplitRuleTask secondTask = new SplitRuleTask(result, right);
        // forks the firstTask
        firstTask.fork();
        // forks the firstTask
        secondTask.fork();
        // join the task in response map
        response.putAll(firstTask.join());
        response.putAll(secondTask.join());
    }
    return response;
}
```

can anyone please help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Fork is also creating a heavy weight process. I suggest you to read thread concepts and then implement multi-threading on them.
More advance way is to create thread-Pool to work on.I suggest you read the below links.

Comment: Please do not provide external links as your answer

Comment: Using Java Thread Pool or fork and join which gives better performance?

Comment: Fork Join pool gives better performance and a robust solution when you have a big task but the overhead is more in this case. You need to take a look into work stealing in Fork/join pool.